# Why does a newly created Android Camera2 MP4 File fail to play on some players, but not others

Tags: android, android-camera2, android-file

I am running into an issue where while using an external library ([link](https://github.com/natario1/CameraView)) and writing a new MP4 file is causing it to be unplayable on multiple players but entirely playable on others.

In theory, it should be immediately playable on all of them, but that is proving not the case. I am creating the video file like this:

```
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss",
                    Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "MyApp_" + timeStamp + "";            
        File video;
        File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES);
        try {
            if(this.saveVideoToGallery){
                storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES);
                if(!storageDir.exists()){
                    boolean createdFolder = false;
                    try {
                        createdFolder = storageDir.mkdir();
                    } catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if(!createdFolder){
                        storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
                    }
                }
                video = new File(storageDir, imageFileName + ".mp4");
            } else {
                if(!storageDir.exists()) {
                    try {
                        storageDir.mkdir();
                    } catch (Exception e) {}
                }
                video = File.createTempFile(
                        imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                        ".mp4",         /* suffix */
                        storageDir      /* directory */
                );
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe){
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            video = new File(storageDir + imageFileName + ".mp4");
        }
```

Note that the boolean

```
saveVideoToGallery
```

Is just a configurable global var that allows writing to an external directory.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the issue is related to the naming schema / Filename logic. I had originally written my name this way:

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm:ss",
                        Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
```

But when I removed the colons (':') and instead used underscores ("_"),

```
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH_mm_ss",
                        Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
```

it fixed the issue.